How to say "to (de)centralize" in Latin?
How does one say "to centralize" or "to decentralize" in Latin?

Some suffixes used for derivation of verbs from nouns or adjectives in Latin are:

-ficō, -ficāre: native Latin suffix related to verb faciō, facere

-issō, -issāre: suffix borrowed from Ancient Greek -ίζω, -ῐ́ζειν in earlier times, probably not productive in later times

-izō, -izāre: suffix borrowed from Ancient Greek -ίζω, -ῐ́ζειν in later times


For "centre" and "central", Latin has:

native noun medium and adjective medius, media, medium

noun centrum borrowed from Ancient Greek κέντρον and adjective centrālis, centrāle


So verbs, which you can create from above adjectives, are:

medificō, medificāre

medizō, medizāre

centrālificō, centrālificāre

centrālizō, centrālizāre


Some prefixes used with verbs, which can reverse their meanings, are dis- and dē-. Of these, dē- seems to often have other meanings than reversal, so I would suggest dis-:

dīmedificō, dīmedificāre

dīmedizō, dīmedizāre

discentrālificō, discentrālificāre

discentrālizō, discentrālizāre


